# On prime numbers of the form $7\times10^n+69$ and the lights out puzzle

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

Consider those natural numbers $n$ such that $7\times10^n+69$ is a prime number. The first $15$ such numbers are $1$, $2$, $3$, $6$, $7$, $8$, $10$, $12$, $13$, $21$, $46$, $68$, $91$, $153$, and $366$. I would say that this is a particulary uninteresting sequence (by the way, this is [sequence A294484 in OEIS](http://oeis.org/A294484)).

However, it suddenly became interesting to me when I noticed that, for each number $n$ on this sequence, the [lights-out problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle.html) has a unique solution on a  $n\times n$ square board. The numbers for which this property holds form the [sequence A076436 in OEIS](http://oeis.org/A076436). The two sequences are not equal; for instance, $15$, $18$, and $20$ belong to the second sequence, but not to the first one. But could it be that every element of the first sequence also belongs to the second one?

Comment: Just glancing at it, it seems like that second sequence has quite a few entries, so probably it would 'capture' many other sequences even if there is no direct connection; certainly if we only go up to some point. Indeed, on the face of it, what could possibly make these sequences connected?  I am not saying it is impossible, but would you have any idea as to what such a connection might be? What would lights-out have to do with 7 and 69? My money is on coincidence ... but then again, with that attitude no interesting discoveries will ever be made! :)

Comment: My answer to your first question is: I have no idea. However, although I only wrote the first $15$ terms of the first sequence in my question, I checked it up to the $18^\text{th}$ term, and they all belong to the second sequence. If it's a coincidence, it's a fairly interesting one, in my opinion.

Comment: I wonder if anyone is using a computer to try to find connections between all these different sequences ... probably, right? Maybe that'll give us some idea how often these kinds of overlaps occur up to a certain number of entries, between what we, as mathematicians, deem to be interesting sequences.

Comment: A quick and dirty calculation indicates to me that 18 terms coinciding with A076436 by pure coincidence should happen with probability about 1/21000, which isn't large but certainly isn't very small. Because of the difficulty involved in calculating A294484, we may never know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer.

Could this be, at least in part, due to different phenomena having a common cause? I notice that, as far as it goes, A076436 contains no $n$ where $n=4\bmod 5$.  $n=4\bmod 5\implies 41\mid 7\cdot10^n+69\implies n\not\in A294484$.

Comment: On the other hand, elements of most of the other arithmetic series which I found which are excluded from A294484 for similar reasons _are_ found in A076436. E.g., 15 + 16 k, 18 k, 17 + 28 k, 42 + 46 k.

Comment: Also, thank you for pointing out to me that it is possible that sequences like A294484 are intimately related to a sieving process similar to that which generates the primes. Never thought about that before.